# Picture (JPEG, PNG) from raw byte array in Linux/OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, arrays

I have a byte array of 80*60 bytes that represent a picture with resolution 80x60 (1 byte per pixel). How do I convert it into picture that could be then used in OpenCV?

I work in Linux with C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `cv::Mat` constructor, and then reshape it using the number of rows.

```
// data is your byte* and sizeOfData is its size in bytes (80x60 in your case I believe)
cv::Mat imageWithData = cv::Mat(sizeOfData, 1, CV_8U, data).clone();
Mat reshapedImage = imageWithData.reshape(0, numberOfRows);
```